# Very Interesting ways to encourage responsible behavior in a project.

Tags: motivation, team-building, project-team, learning

What are the funny and innovative techniques you use as a manager to bring about structure in a project without enforcing rules per say. Here are some examples:

1. Have a Big Balloon with the words “I Broke the Built” on the cubical of the person who breaks the build. The Balloon keeps moving depending on who broke the build last.
2. Another fun rule we have worked in the past is we stop all development the moment the high priority bug screen on our bug tracking system has a scroll bar on it.
3. Another one is a “GJD” (Great Job Done) batch gifted for doing stupid things like introducing a nasty bug in the system.
4. Anyone who breaks the build adds a dollar to the kitty and when we have enough money either donate it or have a party with that money.

A classic is the Joel Spolsky recommendation: Who ever causes a build break the build baby sits the build till someone else breaks it.

The key here is funny techniques which foster no negative feelings but at the same time encourage people to act responsibly in a fun environment.

Do you believe in using fun to encourage responsible behavior in a team environment?

If yes, what are various innovative ways you use with your projects?

A huge interesting list all in one place would be valuable.

Comment: How about a "funny" $100 bill? :)

Comment: That is actually an interesting idea.

Comment: You will be surprised how effective it can be if applied properly

Comment: This is a classic "getting to know you" question, which isn't a constructive format for Stack Exchange. We're closing this as per our site scope changes discussed on [meta].

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

1. **Best practices board.** You put a board near the water cooler and everyone can propose some best practice while making a coffee. It can be something like "let's start pair programming" or whatever one believes would help the organization. Then other people vote it up or down in some way, like adding "me too" sticky or writing "+1." Then you implement highest voted ideas. It's like StackOverflow/StackExchange engine on a piece of hardware (board).
2. **Visualizing effects of the issue and letting people figure out what to do with that.** In one team we had like probation in maintenance project so we could have only certain number of critical and major issues, so we got huge whiteboard, drawn two lines of men - each line represented one level of bugs we might have had (either critical or major) and each man represented a single bug. Then, every time a bug was submitted we crossed one man out so we saw how our "army" was shrinking every time we screwed something up. Not only made it people more aware of potential problems they might cause with their work but also introduced "one for all, all for one" sort of attitude.
3. **Making RPG-like game based on work in the company.** Every employee can enter the game and earn badges/achievements, like "once a trainee" or "survived hard-core project" or "pair programmed for a 10 business days in a row" or whatever good idea you might have. If you crowdsource creation of the game to the people (some moderation would probably be needed though) you'd see how people are adding goals which really add value: they either introduce best practices or focus on project quality etc.